# pad javascript array with value until length is evenly divisible by three

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am given a number of arrays of varying length.  I'd like to pad these arrays (value of padding element can be `0`)  so that the length is evenly divisible by three (I need to create three subarrays of equal length for each array i'm given).

Here's my intended, unsuccessful code with a while loop and an array `push` that should increment `len` until `len % 3 === 0`:

```
function fillArray(value, arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  while (len % 3 !== 0) {
    arr.push(value);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

For example, if given an array as follows

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I'll want to pad (with `0`) until the length is divisible by three:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,0]
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not updating your `len` variable after the initialization.

Instead, use the `length` property directly:

```js
function fillArray(value, arr) {
  while (arr.length % 3 !== 0) {
    arr.push(value);
  }
  return arr;
}

document.write(fillArray(0, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit!  Quick response!